# Sending ics/ical emails via Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, email, calendar, laravel-8, icalendar

I am working on a laravel app and I would like to send meeting/calendar invites that go directly to the users calendar. For example, how calendly does it. The invite should automatically appear on the recipients calendars. Currently I have been able to attach them to the email, but not send directly. This may just be something I missed in the Laravel Mail docs and need to send this exact file instead of an email, but not as an attachment. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this either.

I currently looked around stackoverflow and did not find a clean implementation of this for laravel despite it being a pretty common feature. I have tried Spatie, Eluceo, and INSAN packages on github and did not have much luck. The code below works for downloading a .ics file.

I would appreciate any helpful comments! I have spent a long time looking into this already with little progress.

```
use INSAN\ICS;
$properities = [
            'uid' => uniqid(),
            'sequence' => 0,
            'description' => 'Event Invitation via email.',
            'dtstart' => date('2021-05-01 09:00'),
            'dtend' => date('2021-05-01 10:00'),
            'summary' => 'This is an event invitation sent through email.',
            'location' => 'VR Punjab, S.A.S Nagar, Chandigarh',
            'url' => 'www.example.com',
        ];

    $ics_file = new ICS($properities);
    return $ics_file->toString();
```

Comment: You can't 'send' direct to a users main calendar.   You can ask them to subscribe to a calendar url which is theirs & theirs alone and then make updates to that calendar feed which will then appear automatically.

Comment: If that is the case, how does Calendly do this for anyone? I have not signed up for the service, but when I book a meeting it goes directly on my calendar and sends the invitation.

Comment: You take an action it goes on your calendar.  I’d be supremely annoyed if anyone could force events onto my calendar unless I’d said it was ok or I had a url for that separate calendar.  Like Google calendar one can set it up so that events that one is invited to (using the gmail email) go directly onto ones google calendar.     You can make that happen for other people, only if they choose to do that.   I don’t use calendly either - perhaps within their ecosystem that’s how it works. Shouldn’t do that externally for everyone.